# Combining Mutiple Input Xml files into one large xml file

Tags: xslt

I did not create this xslt, but it is used to group extracted data by EDOC number, which is required.  The problem is, it creates hundreds of individual .xml files (because the input is hundreds of individual xml files).  Is there a simple way to modify this xslt to create one xml record with the multiple files inside?  I know part of the reason is because it does a for-each select on each file, but I'm not sure how to modify this to get the results I need.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:redirect="org.apache.xalan.xslt.extensions.Redirect" extension-element-prefixes="redirect">
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:for-each select="AchXmlData">
    <xsl:variable name="EDOC" select="F47056D1EDOC"/>
        <redirect:write select="concat('/gis5/ACHOutbound/',$EDOC,'_',position(),'.','xml')">
            <AchXml>
                <AchXmlData>
                    <!-- EDI Payment Order Header -->
                    <F47056D1EDTY>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1EDTY"/>   </F47056D1EDTY>
                    <F47056D1EDSQ>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1EDSQ"/>   </F47056D1EDSQ>
                    <F47056D1EKCO>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1EKCO"/>   </F47056D1EKCO>
                    <F47056D1EDOC>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1EDOC"/>   </F47056D1EDOC>
                    <F47056D1EDCT>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1EDCT"/>   </F47056D1EDCT>
                    <F47056D1EDLN>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1EDLN"/>   </F47056D1EDLN>
                    <F47056D1EDST>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1EDST"/>   </F47056D1EDST>
                    <F47056D1EDFT>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1EDFT"/>   </F47056D1EDFT>
                    <F47056D1EDDT>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1EDDT"/>   </F47056D1EDDT>
                    <F47056D1EDER>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1EDER"/>   </F47056D1EDER>
                    <F47056D1EDDL>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1EDDL"/>   </F47056D1EDDL>
                    <F47056D1EDSP>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1EDSP"/>   </F47056D1EDSP>
                    <F47056D1EDBT>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1EDBT"/>   </F47056D1EDBT>
                    <F47056D1PNID>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1PNID"/>   </F47056D1PNID>
                    <F47056D1ICU>   <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1ICU"/>    </F47056D1ICU>
                    <F47056D1ICUT>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1ICUT"/>   </F47056D1ICUT>
                    <F47056D1KCO>   <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1KCO"/>    </F47056D1KCO>
                    <F47056D1CO>    <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1CO"/> </F47056D1CO>
                    <F47056D1MCU>   <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1MCU"/>    </F47056D1MCU>
                    <F47056D1DOCM>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1DOCM"/>   </F47056D1DOCM>
                    <F47056D1DCTM>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1DCTM"/>   </F47056D1DCTM>
                    <F47056D1SFXM>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1SFXM"/>   </F47056D1SFXM>
                    <F47056D1DMTJ>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1DMTJ"/>   </F47056D1DMTJ>
                    <F47056D1PYIN>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1PYIN"/>   </F47056D1PYIN>
                    <F47056D1PRMK>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1PRMK"/>   </F47056D1PRMK>
                    <F47056D1AN8>   <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1AN8"/>    </F47056D1AN8>
                    <F47056D1PYE>   <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1PYE"/>    </F47056D1PYE>
                    <F47056D1CRRM>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1CRRM"/>   </F47056D1CRRM>
                    <F47056D1DMCD>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1DMCD"/>   </F47056D1DMCD>
                    <F47056D1CRCD>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1CRCD"/>   </F47056D1CRCD>
                    <F47056D1CDEC>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1CDEC"/>   </F47056D1CDEC>
                    <F47056D1CRR>   <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1CRR"/>    </F47056D1CRR>
                    <F47056D1THCD>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1THCD"/>   </F47056D1THCD>
                    <F47056D1DGJ>   <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1DGJ"/>    </F47056D1DGJ>
                    <F47056D1FY>    <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1FY"/> </F47056D1FY>
                    <F47056D1CTRY>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1CTRY"/>   </F47056D1CTRY>
                    <F47056D1PN>    <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1PN"/> </F47056D1PN>
                    <F47056D1TTOT>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1TTOT"/>   </F47056D1TTOT>
                    <F47056D1AC01>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1AC01"/>   </F47056D1AC01>
                    <F47056D1AC02>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1AC02"/>   </F47056D1AC02>
                    <F47056D1AC03>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1AC03"/>   </F47056D1AC03>
                    <F47056D1AC04>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1AC04"/>   </F47056D1AC04>
                    <F47056D1AC05>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1AC05"/>   </F47056D1AC05>
                    <F47056D1AC06>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1AC06"/>   </F47056D1AC06>
                    <F47056D1AC07>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1AC07"/>   </F47056D1AC07>
                    <F47056D1AC08>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1AC08"/>   </F47056D1AC08>
                    <F47056D1AC09>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1AC09"/>   </F47056D1AC09>
                    <F47056D1AC10>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1AC10"/>   </F47056D1AC10>
                    <F47056D1ATE>   <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1ATE"/>    </F47056D1ATE>
                    <F47056D1ATR>   <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1ATR"/>    </F47056D1ATR>
                    <F47056D1ATP>   <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1ATP"/>    </F47056D1ATP>
                    <F47056D1ATO>   <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1ATO"/>    </F47056D1ATO>
                    <F47056D1ATPR>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1ATPR"/>   </F47056D1ATPR>
                    <F47056D1AT1>   <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1AT1"/>    </F47056D1AT1>
                    <F47056D1AT2>   <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1AT2"/>    </F47056D1AT2>
                    <F47056D1AT3>   <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1AT3"/>    </F47056D1AT3>
                    <F47056D1AT4>   <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1AT4"/>    </F47056D1AT4>
                    <F47056D1AT5>   <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1AT5"/>    </F47056D1AT5>
                    <F47056D1TNN>   <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1TNN"/>    </F47056D1TNN>
                    <F47056D1URCD>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1URCD"/>   </F47056D1URCD>
                    <F47056D1URDT>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1URDT"/>   </F47056D1URDT>
                    <F47056D1URAT>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1URAT"/>   </F47056D1URAT>
                    <F47056D1URAB>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1URAB"/>   </F47056D1URAB>
                    <F47056D1URRF>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1URRF"/>   </F47056D1URRF>
                    <F47056D1TORG>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1TORG"/>   </F47056D1TORG>
                    <F47056D1USER>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1USER"/>   </F47056D1USER>
                    <F47056D1PID>   <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1PID"/>    </F47056D1PID>
                    <F47056D1JOBN>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1JOBN"/>   </F47056D1JOBN>
                    <F47056D1UPMJ>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1UPMJ"/>   </F47056D1UPMJ>
                    <F47056D1TDAY>  <xsl:value-of select="F47056D1TDAY"/>   </F47056D1TDAY>
                    <xsl:for-each select="F470561Data">
                        <F470561Data>
                            <!-- EDI Payment Order Bank N & A -->
                            <F470561D2EDTY> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2EDTY"/>  </F470561D2EDTY>
                            <F470561D2EDSQ> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2EDSQ"/>  </F470561D2EDSQ>
                            <F470561D2EKCO> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2EKCO"/>  </F470561D2EKCO>
                            <F470561D2EDOC> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2EDOC"/>  </F470561D2EDOC>
                            <F470561D2EDCT> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2EDCT"/>  </F470561D2EDCT>
                            <F470561D2EDLN> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2EDLN"/>  </F470561D2EDLN>
                            <F470561D2EDSP> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2EDSP"/>  </F470561D2EDSP>
                            <F470561D2EDBT> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2EDBT"/>  </F470561D2EDBT>
                            <F470561D2ICU>  <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2ICU"/>   </F470561D2ICU>
                            <F470561D2ICUT> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2ICUT"/>  </F470561D2ICUT>
                            <F470561D2KCO>  <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2KCO"/>   </F470561D2KCO>
                            <F470561D2ADDS> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2ADDS"/>  </F470561D2ADDS>
                            <F470561D2CO>   <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2CO"/>    </F470561D2CO>
                            <F470561D2MCU>  <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2MCU"/>   </F470561D2MCU>
                            <F470561D2DOCM> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2DOCM"/>  </F470561D2DOCM>
                            <F470561D2DCTM> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2DCTM"/>  </F470561D2DCTM>
                            <F470561D2SFXM> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2SFXM"/>  </F470561D2SFXM>
                            <F470561D2AN8>  <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2AN8"/>   </F470561D2AN8>
                            <F470561D2AR1>  <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2AR1"/>   </F470561D2AR1>
                            <F470561D2PH1>  <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2PH1"/>   </F470561D2PH1>
                            <F470561D2AR2>  <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2AR2"/>   </F470561D2AR2>
                            <F470561D2PH2>  <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2PH2"/>   </F470561D2PH2>
                            <F470561D2ALPH> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2ALPH"/>  </F470561D2ALPH>
                            <F470561D2NAID> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2NAID"/>  </F470561D2NAID>
                            <F470561D2ADD6> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2ADD6"/>  </F470561D2ADD6>
                            <F470561D2ADD1> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2ADD1"/>  </F470561D2ADD1>
                            <F470561D2ADD2> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2ADD2"/>  </F470561D2ADD2>
                            <F470561D2ADD3> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2ADD3"/>  </F470561D2ADD3>
                            <F470561D2ADD4> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2ADD4"/>  </F470561D2ADD4>
                            <F470561D2ADD5> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2ADD5"/>  </F470561D2ADD5>
                            <F470561D2ADDZ> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2ADDZ"/>  </F470561D2ADDZ>
                            <F470561D2CTR>  <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2CTR"/>   </F470561D2CTR>
                            <F470561D2EDCI> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2EDCI"/>  </F470561D2EDCI>
                            <F470561D2IDC>  <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2IDC"/>   </F470561D2IDC>
                            <F470561D2DL01> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2DL01"/>  </F470561D2DL01>
                            <F470561D2CBNK> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2CBNK"/>  </F470561D2CBNK>
                            <F470561D2TNST> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2TNST"/>  </F470561D2TNST>
                            <F470561D2CHKD> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2CHKD"/>  </F470561D2CHKD>
                            <F470561D2TORG> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2TORG"/>  </F470561D2TORG>
                            <F470561D2USER> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2USER"/>  </F470561D2USER>
                            <F470561D2PID>  <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2PID"/>   </F470561D2PID>
                            <F470561D2JOBN> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2JOBN"/>  </F470561D2JOBN>
                            <F470561D2UPMJ> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2UPMJ"/>  </F470561D2UPMJ>
                            <F470561D2TDAY> <xsl:value-of select="F470561D2TDAY"/>  </F470561D2TDAY>
                        </F470561Data>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:for-each select="F470562Data">
                        <F470562Data>
                            <!-- EDI Payment Order Vendor N & A -->
                            <F470562D4EDTY> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4EDTY"/>  </F470562D4EDTY>
                            <F470562D4EDSQ> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4EDSQ"/>  </F470562D4EDSQ>
                            <F470562D4EKCO> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4EKCO"/>  </F470562D4EKCO>
                            <F470562D4EDOC> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4EDOC"/>  </F470562D4EDOC>
                            <F470562D4EDCT> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4EDCT"/>  </F470562D4EDCT>
                            <F470562D4EDLN> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4EDLN"/>  </F470562D4EDLN>
                            <F470562D4EDSP> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4EDSP"/>  </F470562D4EDSP>
                            <F470562D4EDBT> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4EDBT"/>  </F470562D4EDBT>
                            <F470562D4ICU>  <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4ICU"/>   </F470562D4ICU>
                            <F470562D4ICUT> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4ICUT"/>  </F470562D4ICUT>
                            <F470562D4KCO>  <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4KCO"/>   </F470562D4KCO>
                            <F470562D4CO>   <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4CO"/>    </F470562D4CO>
                            <F470562D4MCU>  <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4MCU"/>   </F470562D4MCU>
                            <F470562D4DOCM> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4DOCM"/>  </F470562D4DOCM>
                            <F470562D4DCTM> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4DCTM"/>  </F470562D4DCTM>
                            <F470562D4SFXM> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4SFXM"/>  </F470562D4SFXM>
                            <F470562D4NAID> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4NAID"/>  </F470562D4NAID>
                            <F470562D4AN8>  <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4AN8"/>   </F470562D4AN8>
                            <F470562D4AR1>  <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4AR1"/>   </F470562D4AR1>
                            <F470562D4PH1>  <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4PH1"/>   </F470562D4PH1>
                            <F470562D4AR2>  <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4AR2"/>   </F470562D4AR2>
                            <F470562D4PH2>  <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4PH2"/>   </F470562D4PH2>
                            <F470562D4ALPH> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4ALPH"/>  </F470562D4ALPH>
                            <F470562D4ADD1> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4ADD1"/>  </F470562D4ADD1>
                            <F470562D4ADD2> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4ADD2"/>  </F470562D4ADD2>
                            <F470562D4ADD3> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4ADD3"/>  </F470562D4ADD3>
                            <F470562D4ADD4> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4ADD4"/>  </F470562D4ADD4>
                            <F470562D4ADD5> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4ADD5"/>  </F470562D4ADD5>
                            <F470562D4ADD6> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4ADD6"/>  </F470562D4ADD6>
                            <F470562D4ADDS> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4ADDS"/>  </F470562D4ADDS>
                            <F470562D4ADDZ> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4ADDZ"/>  </F470562D4ADDZ>
                            <F470562D4CTR>  <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4CTR"/>   </F470562D4CTR>
                            <F470562D4EDCI> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4EDCI"/>  </F470562D4EDCI>
                            <F470562D4IDC>  <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4IDC"/>   </F470562D4IDC>
                            <F470562D4DL01> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4DL01"/>  </F470562D4DL01>
                            <F470562D4CBNK> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4CBNK"/>  </F470562D4CBNK>
                            <F470562D4TNST> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4TNST"/>  </F470562D4TNST>
                            <F470562D4CHKD> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4CHKD"/>  </F470562D4CHKD>
                            <F470562D4TORG> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4TORG"/>  </F470562D4TORG>
                            <F470562D4USER> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4USER"/>  </F470562D4USER>
                            <F470562D4PID>  <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4PID"/>   </F470562D4PID>
                            <F470562D4JOBN> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4JOBN"/>  </F470562D4JOBN>
                            <F470562D4UPMJ> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4UPMJ"/>  </F470562D4UPMJ>
                            <F470562D4TDAY> <xsl:value-of select="F470562D4TDAY"/>  </F470562D4TDAY>
                        </F470562Data>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:for-each select="F470563Data">
                        <F470563Data>
                            <!-- EDI Payment Order Payee N & A -->
                            <F470563D5EDTY> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5EDTY"/>  </F470563D5EDTY>
                            <F470563D5EDSQ> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5EDSQ"/>  </F470563D5EDSQ>
                            <F470563D5EKCO> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5EKCO"/>  </F470563D5EKCO>
                            <F470563D5EDOC> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5EDOC"/>  </F470563D5EDOC>
                            <F470563D5EDCT> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5EDCT"/>  </F470563D5EDCT>
                            <F470563D5EDLN> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5EDLN"/>  </F470563D5EDLN>
                            <F470563D5EDSP> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5EDSP"/>  </F470563D5EDSP>
                            <F470563D5EDBT> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5EDBT"/>  </F470563D5EDBT>
                            <F470563D5ICU>  <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5ICU"/>   </F470563D5ICU>
                            <F470563D5ICUT> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5ICUT"/>  </F470563D5ICUT>
                            <F470563D5KCO>  <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5KCO"/>   </F470563D5KCO>
                            <F470563D5CO>   <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5CO"/>    </F470563D5CO>
                            <F470563D5MCU>  <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5MCU"/>   </F470563D5MCU>
                            <F470563D5DOCM> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5DOCM"/>  </F470563D5DOCM>
                            <F470563D5DCTM> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5DCTM"/>  </F470563D5DCTM>
                            <F470563D5SFXM> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5SFXM"/>  </F470563D5SFXM>
                            <F470563D5NAID> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5NAID"/>  </F470563D5NAID>
                            <F470563D5AN8>  <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5AN8"/>   </F470563D5AN8>
                            <F470563D5AR1>  <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5AR1"/>   </F470563D5AR1>
                            <F470563D5PH1>  <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5PH1"/>   </F470563D5PH1>
                            <F470563D5AR2>  <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5AR2"/>   </F470563D5AR2>
                            <F470563D5PH2>  <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5PH2"/>   </F470563D5PH2>
                            <F470563D5ALPH> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5ALPH"/>  </F470563D5ALPH>
                            <F470563D5ADD1> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5ADD1"/>  </F470563D5ADD1>
                            <F470563D5ADD2> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5ADD2"/>  </F470563D5ADD2>
                            <F470563D5ADD3> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5ADD3"/>  </F470563D5ADD3>
                            <F470563D5ADD4> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5ADD4"/>  </F470563D5ADD4>
                            <F470563D5ADD5> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5ADD5"/>  </F470563D5ADD5>
                            <F470563D5ADD6> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5ADD6"/>  </F470563D5ADD6>
                            <F470563D5ADDS> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5ADDS"/>  </F470563D5ADDS>
                            <F470563D5ADDZ> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5ADDZ"/>  </F470563D5ADDZ>
                            <F470563D5CTR>  <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5CTR"/>   </F470563D5CTR>
                            <F470563D5EDCI> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5EDCI"/>  </F470563D5EDCI>
                            <F470563D5IDC>  <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5IDC"/>   </F470563D5IDC>
                            <F470563D5DL01> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5DL01"/>  </F470563D5DL01>
                            <F470563D5CBNK> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5CBNK"/>  </F470563D5CBNK>
                            <F470563D5TNST> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5TNST"/>  </F470563D5TNST>
                            <F470563D5CHKD> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5CHKD"/>  </F470563D5CHKD>
                            <F470563D5TORG> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5TORG"/>  </F470563D5TORG>
                            <F470563D5USER> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5USER"/>  </F470563D5USER>
                            <F470563D5PID>  <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5PID"/>   </F470563D5PID>
                            <F470563D5JOBN> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5JOBN"/>  </F470563D5JOBN>
                            <F470563D5UPMJ> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5UPMJ"/>  </F470563D5UPMJ>
                            <F470563D5TDAY> <xsl:value-of select="F470563D5TDAY"/>  </F470563D5TDAY>
                        </F470563Data>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:for-each select="F47057Data">
                        <F47057Data>
                            <!-- EDI Payment Order Remittance Advice -->
                            <F47057D3EDTY>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3EDTY"/>   </F47057D3EDTY>
                            <F47057D3EDSQ>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3EDSQ"/>   </F47057D3EDSQ>
                            <F47057D3EKCO>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3EKCO"/>   </F47057D3EKCO>
                            <F47057D3EDOC>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3EDOC"/>   </F47057D3EDOC>
                            <F47057D3EDCT>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3EDCT"/>   </F47057D3EDCT>
                            <F47057D3EDLN>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3EDLN"/>   </F47057D3EDLN>
                            <F47057D3EDST>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3EDST"/>   </F47057D3EDST>
                            <F47057D3EDFT>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3EDFT"/>   </F47057D3EDFT>
                            <F47057D3EDDT>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3EDDT"/>   </F47057D3EDDT>
                            <F47057D3EDER>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3EDER"/>   </F47057D3EDER>
                            <F47057D3EDDL>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3EDDL"/>   </F47057D3EDDL>
                            <F47057D3EDSP>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3EDSP"/>   </F47057D3EDSP>
                            <F47057D3EDBT>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3EDBT"/>   </F47057D3EDBT>
                            <F47057D3PNID>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3PNID"/>   </F47057D3PNID>
                            <F47057D3ICU>   <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3ICU"/>    </F47057D3ICU>
                            <F47057D3ICUT>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3ICUT"/>   </F47057D3ICUT>
                            <F47057D3KCO>   <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3KCO"/>    </F47057D3KCO>
                            <F47057D3CO>    <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3CO"/> </F47057D3CO>
                            <F47057D3MCU>   <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3MCU"/>    </F47057D3MCU>
                            <F47057D3DOCM>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3DOCM"/>   </F47057D3DOCM>
                            <F47057D3DCTM>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3DCTM"/>   </F47057D3DCTM>
                            <F47057D3SFXM>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3SFXM"/>   </F47057D3SFXM>
                            <F47057D3DMTJ>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3DMTJ"/>   </F47057D3DMTJ>
                            <F47057D3PYIN>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3PYIN"/>   </F47057D3PYIN>
                            <F47057D3PRMK>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3PRMK"/>   </F47057D3PRMK>
                            <F47057D3AN8>   <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3AN8"/>    </F47057D3AN8>
                            <F47057D3PYE>   <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3PYE"/>    </F47057D3PYE>
                            <F47057D3CRRM>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3CRRM"/>   </F47057D3CRRM>
                            <F47057D3DMCD>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3DMCD"/>   </F47057D3DMCD>
                            <F47057D3CRCD>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3CRCD"/>   </F47057D3CRCD>
                            <F47057D3CDEC>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3CDEC"/>   </F47057D3CDEC>
                            <F47057D3CRR>   <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3CRR"/>    </F47057D3CRR>
                            <F47057D3DCT>   <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3DCT"/>    </F47057D3DCT>
                            <F47057D3DOC>   <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3DOC"/>    </F47057D3DOC>
                            <F47057D3SFX>   <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3SFX"/>    </F47057D3SFX>
                            <F47057D3VINV>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3VINV"/>   </F47057D3VINV>
                            <F47057D3SFXE>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3SFXE"/>   </F47057D3SFXE>
                            <F47057D3DCTA>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3DCTA"/>   </F47057D3DCTA>
                            <F47057D3DIVJ>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3DIVJ"/>   </F47057D3DIVJ>
                            <F47057D3DDJ>   <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3DDJ"/>    </F47057D3DDJ>
                            <F47057D3DDNJ>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3DDNJ"/>   </F47057D3DDNJ>
                            <F47057D3DSVJ>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3DSVJ"/>   </F47057D3DSVJ>
                            <F47057D3ODOC>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3ODOC"/>   </F47057D3ODOC>
                            <F47057D3ODCT>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3ODCT"/>   </F47057D3ODCT>
                            <F47057D3OSFX>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3OSFX"/>   </F47057D3OSFX>
                            <F47057D3OKCO>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3OKCO"/>   </F47057D3OKCO>
                            <F47057D3QUAL>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3QUAL"/>   </F47057D3QUAL>
                            <F47057D3PO>    <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3PO"/> </F47057D3PO>
                            <F47057D3PDCT>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3PDCT"/>   </F47057D3PDCT>
                            <F47057D3PKCO>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3PKCO"/>   </F47057D3PKCO>
                            <F47057D3LNID>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3LNID"/>   </F47057D3LNID>
                            <F47057D3SFXO>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3SFXO"/>   </F47057D3SFXO>
                            <F47057D3OPSQ>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3OPSQ"/>   </F47057D3OPSQ>
                            <F47057D3ITM>   <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3ITM"/>    </F47057D3ITM>
                            <F47057D3VR01>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3VR01"/>   </F47057D3VR01>
                            <F47057D3AG>    <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3AG"/> </F47057D3AG>
                            <F47057D3ADSC>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3ADSC"/>   </F47057D3ADSC>
                            <F47057D3PAAP>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3PAAP"/>   </F47057D3PAAP>
                            <F47057D3ADSA>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3ADSA"/>   </F47057D3ADSA>
                            <F47057D3ATXN>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3ATXN"/>   </F47057D3ATXN>
                            <F47057D3ATXA>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3ATXA"/>   </F47057D3ATXA>
                            <F47057D3STAM>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3STAM"/>   </F47057D3STAM>
                            <F47057D3ACR>   <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3ACR"/>    </F47057D3ACR>
                            <F47057D3CDS>   <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3CDS"/>    </F47057D3CDS>
                            <F47057D3PFAP>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3PFAP"/>   </F47057D3PFAP>
                            <F47057D3CDSA>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3CDSA"/>   </F47057D3CDSA>
                            <F47057D3CTXN>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3CTXN"/>   </F47057D3CTXN>
                            <F47057D3CTXA>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3CTXA"/>   </F47057D3CTXA>
                            <F47057D3CTAM>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3CTAM"/>   </F47057D3CTAM>
                            <F47057D3TGA>   <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3TGA"/>    </F47057D3TGA>
                            <F47057D3TDSC>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3TDSC"/>   </F47057D3TDSC>
                            <F47057D3TAP>   <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3TAP"/>    </F47057D3TAP>
                            <F47057D3TDSA>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3TDSA"/>   </F47057D3TDSA>
                            <F47057D3TTXN>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3TTXN"/>   </F47057D3TTXN>
                            <F47057D3TTXA>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3TTXA"/>   </F47057D3TTXA>
                            <F47057D3TTAM>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3TTAM"/>   </F47057D3TTAM>
                            <F47057D3TXA1>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3TXA1"/>   </F47057D3TXA1>
                            <F47057D3EXR1>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3EXR1"/>   </F47057D3EXR1>
                            <F47057D3CRC>   <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3CRC"/>    </F47057D3CRC>
                            <F47057D3RMK>   <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3RMK"/>    </F47057D3RMK>
                            <F47057D3NSF>   <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3NSF"/>    </F47057D3NSF>
                            <F47057D3AR>    <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3AR"/> </F47057D3AR>
                            <F47057D3PTC>   <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3PTC"/>    </F47057D3PTC>
                            <F47057D3RF>    <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3RF"/> </F47057D3RF>
                            <F47057D3DRF>   <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3DRF"/>    </F47057D3DRF>
                            <F47057D3FNLP>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3FNLP"/>   </F47057D3FNLP>
                            <F47057D3U>     <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3U"/>  </F47057D3U>
                            <F47057D3UM>    <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3UM"/> </F47057D3UM>
                            <F47057D3ALT6>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3ALT6"/>   </F47057D3ALT6>
                            <F47057D3RP1>   <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3RP1"/>    </F47057D3RP1>
                            <F47057D3RP2>   <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3RP2"/>    </F47057D3RP2>
                            <F47057D3RP3>   <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3RP3"/>    </F47057D3RP3>
                            <F47057D3GLC>   <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3GLC"/>    </F47057D3GLC>
                            <F47057D3GLBA>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3GLBA"/>   </F47057D3GLBA>
                            <F47057D3AM>    <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3AM"/> </F47057D3AM>
                            <F47057D3AID2>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3AID2"/>   </F47057D3AID2>
                            <F47057D3AM2>   <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3AM2"/>    </F47057D3AM2>
                            <F47057D3UNIT>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3UNIT"/>   </F47057D3UNIT>
                            <F47057D3MCU2>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3MCU2"/>   </F47057D3MCU2>
                            <F47057D3OBJ>   <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3OBJ"/>    </F47057D3OBJ>
                            <F47057D3SUB>   <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3SUB"/>    </F47057D3SUB>
                            <F47057D3SBLT>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3SBLT"/>   </F47057D3SBLT>
                            <F47057D3SBL>   <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3SBL"/>    </F47057D3SBL>
                            <F47057D3BAID>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3BAID"/>   </F47057D3BAID>
                            <F47057D3PYID>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3PYID"/>   </F47057D3PYID>
                            <F47057D3RC5>   <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3RC5"/>    </F47057D3RC5>
                            <F47057D3HCRR>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3HCRR"/>   </F47057D3HCRR>
                            <F47057D3HDGJ>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3HDGJ"/>   </F47057D3HDGJ>
                            <F47057D3TXA3>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3TXA3"/>   </F47057D3TXA3>
                            <F47057D3EXR3>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3EXR3"/>   </F47057D3EXR3>
                            <F47057D3URCD>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3URCD"/>   </F47057D3URCD>
                            <F47057D3URDT>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3URDT"/>   </F47057D3URDT>
                            <F47057D3URAT>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3URAT"/>   </F47057D3URAT>
                            <F47057D3URAB>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3URAB"/>   </F47057D3URAB>
                            <F47057D3URRF>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3URRF"/>   </F47057D3URRF>
                            <F47057D3TORG>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3TORG"/>   </F47057D3TORG>
                            <F47057D3USER>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3USER"/>   </F47057D3USER>
                            <F47057D3PID>   <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3PID"/>    </F47057D3PID>
                            <F47057D3JOBN>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3JOBN"/>   </F47057D3JOBN>
                            <F47057D3UPMJ>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3UPMJ"/>   </F47057D3UPMJ>
                            <F47057D3TDAY>  <xsl:value-of select="F47057D3TDAY"/>   </F47057D3TDAY>
                        </F47057Data>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </AchXmlData>
            </AchXml>
        </redirect:write>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can you explain how "one xml record with the multiple files inside" looks exactly? Where does that XSLT 1 code process "hundreds of individual xml files"? If run with Xalan it creates multiple result files with the "redirect:write" element so you could remove that for a start and keep its content, that way you get a single result.

Comment: Thanks.  Have removed the current XSLT step entirely - it is not necessary for my new process.  Now I have one large XML file.  Not sure why this was written in this manner.  The output from the step prior to this gives me what I need.